# Jquery selectbox gives errors with IE 7

Tags: jquery, html

Im using the following code and its working on all the browsers Except IE 7 this error occurs when the number of options exceeds  1900 options anyone have a solution for it  .when I click a value it gives me a javascript error(A script on this page is causing Internet Explorer to run slowly).I appreciate your help.Thank you.This is the code that im using.

```
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

   <head>

           <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

           <link href="http://select-box.googlecode.com/svn/tags/0.2/jquery.selectbox.css"type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

           <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

           <script type="text/javascript" src="http://select-box.googlecode.com/svn/tags/0.2/jquery.selectbox-0.2.min.js"></script>

         <title>Untitled Document</title>

      </head>



      <body> 

       <SCRIPT Language="JavaScript">

           <!-- 

           document.write('<select id="language">')

           for(i = 0; i < 2500; i++){

           document.write('<option value="javascript">'+i+'</option>') 

             }

            document.write('</select>')

           //-->

           </SCRIPT>

         </body> 

     <script type="text/javascript">

         $(function () {

         $("#language").selectbox();


       });

   </script>



    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you try a text input for the number? i don't see the point in scrolling over 2500 numbers... of course you could use two selects one for the first 1250 options and another one for the others